# Is it possible to manually set / toggle the UserInterfaceStyle / Dark Mode per App?

Tags: ios, ios-darkmode, uitraitcollection, uiuserinterfacestyle

I have updated my iOS 11+ to support Dark Mode when being used on iOS 13. This works fine when the UserInterfaceStyle / Dark Mode is enabled or disable in the device settings.

However, I would like to give users the option to activate / deactivate Dark Mode for my app only.

Using a switch to override / toggle the `UserInterfaceStyle` of the current app window is no big deal:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = (uiStyleSwitch.isOn ? .dark : .light)
    }
}
```

**But this approach has <s>two</s> one downside<s>s</s>:**

- <s>I would like to toggle between Dark Mode, Light Mode and System preferences where the first two forces one mode or the other over the current system settings and the third uses the system settings. But how to go back to "use system settings" after `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` has been set? Using `.unspecified` seems to work, but the behaviour is not really documented. Is it save to be used?</s> Can be solved using `.uspecified` (see comments)
- This only works for the current available windows. However, different 3rd party controls and libraries create their own windows (e.g. to display toast message, popups, etc.). Since I cannot control the creation of these windows I cannot override their style.

**So the question is: Is it possible to dynamically override the UserInterfaceStyle for the complete app?**

I know that I can choose the style in the `Info.plist` but this cannot be changed by the user of course.

Comment: Did you try using [`unspecified`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle/unspecified) to go back to using system settings?

Comment: Using `.unspecified` seems to work, but the behaviour is not really documented. Is it save to be used?

Comment: From the docs of `unspecified`: "Choose this option when you want to follow the system's interface style."

Comment: So yes, it's the way to go here.

Comment: Yea, not sure what you mean by "not really documented" — I provided a link to the documentation.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I removed this part from the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.unspecified`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle/unspecified) to revert to the system settings for the interface style.

> Choose this option when you want to follow the system's interface style

As for the other part of your question, it would probably depend on what is being presented and what callbacks you can access.

Comment: Thanks, the first part is solved. I already checked the third party controls and they do not offer callbacks to influence how the create their windows. Most likely I could create a hacky solution or create my own (sub)version of the controls. However, the question is, wether there is a *official* way to manually set the style for (all parts) of my app (including all windows)

Comment: It really depends on what windows / views you're talking about and how they're being presented. You might want to consider creating a new question and providing specific code examples and images to show the problem.